# Interpretting output from fsck

Tags: git, fsck

I'm working on a project using `git`, and ran into some problems: [How to diagnose and fix git fatal unable to read tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870895/how-to-diagnose-and-fix-git-fatal-unable-to-read-tree) The comments suggested that my issue might be related to my file system, so I have tried a few things but wanted to check them here.

I booted `Ubuntu 12.10` from a live cd and ran

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

which gave this output

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x3c7b1a0a

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    22499327    11248640   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    22499328    22704127      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        22704128   521973347   249634610    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4       521973758   976771071   227398657    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       958926848   976771071     8922112   82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       521973760   958926847   218476544   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdd: 1998 MB, 1998585856 bytes
16 heads, 32 sectors/track, 7624 cylinders, total 3903488 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0004d834

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1              32     3903487     1951728    b  W95 FAT32
```

I then ran

```
sudo fsck /dev/sda6
```

which gave

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1
e2fsck 1.42 (29-Nov-2011)
/dev/sda6: clean, 832860/13656064 files, 5764993/54619136 blocks
```

Does this mean that my file system is ok? Are there any other commands that I should check?

I have tentatively added the `git` tag to this question, as that's really where the problem seems to lie- I'm not entirely sure what the status of my file system is, but would love to get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 1):

Everything appears to be fine with your file system. You haven't got any of the [fsck error messages](http://www.shrubbery.net/solaris9ab/SUNWaadm/SYSADV2/p104.html), it completed the scan successfully. This issue should be related to git alone. Check my comment at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870895/how-to-diagnose-and-fix-git-fatal-unable-to-read-tree).